# Creating fusioncharts from database with variable where-condition

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, fusioncharts

I'm creating FusionCharts with data from my database. It works if I set a static where-condition with a variable set in the code ($kommunenr = '3001';). But I would like the user of the website to choose which data the chart is based on, by inserting a number in a form field, i.e. 3018. So the value of the variable should come from the user's choice. But when I test the variable seems empty.

My code is based on these tutorials:
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/tutorials/php-mysql-charts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqavhILvBVU
https://a1websitepro.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit-with-php-processing/2/

I have the following files:

valginfo.php (the main page)

skjema.js (get the data (the number) from the form on the main page)

chart_sample.php (lists the data from the database)

app.js (creates the chart)

I have tried to find the error by both posting the content from chart_sample.php in a div on the mainpage, and in an iframe. And of course googling.

My query in my chart-data.php (choosing the data to use in making the chart):

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM valg19_kommune WHERE kommunenr = $kommunenr AND kandidatnr = 1 ORDER BY kommunenr, sortering, kandidatnr LIMIT 500";
```

It works if the variable is static, set like this:

```php
$kommunenr = '3001';
```

But when I set the variable like this, it looks empty:

```php
$nr=$_POST['nr1'];
$kommunenr=$nr;
```

I expect the posted number to be stored as the value of the variable and beeing part of the query, but it is not. When I echo the query and the result from chart_sample.php into a div on the main page, I looks perfect:

```php
SELECT * FROM valg19_kommune WHERE kommunenr = 3018 AND kandidatnr = 1 ORDER BY kommunenr, sortering, kandidatnr LIMIT 500
[{"label":"Fremskrittspartiet","value":"42","color":"#000099","tooltext":"Elisabeth Stene"},{"label":"H\u00f8yre","value":"64","color":"#3366ff","tooltext":"Benedicte Dyvik"},{"label":"Kristelig Folkeparti","value":"56","color":"#ffff00","tooltext":"Brynjar H\u00f8idebraaten"},{"label":"Senterpartiet","value":"45","color":"#00cc00","tooltext":"Reidar Kaabbel"},{"label":"Arbeiderpartiet","value":"44","color":"#ff3300","tooltext":"Kai Guttulsr\u00f8d"},{"label":"SV - Sosialistisk Venstreparti","value":"39","color":"#ff4d4d","tooltext":"Tore Andersen"},{"label":"R\u00f8dt","value":"37","color":"#cc0000","tooltext":"Martin Werner Olsen"}]
```

But in my iFrame this is displayed:

```php
SELECT * FROM valg19_kommune WHERE kommunenr = AND kandidatnr = 1 ORDER BY kommunenr, sortering, kandidatnr LIMIT 500[]
```

The iframe content is not updated when I submit the number.

How can I make sure the chart is made based on the number entered by the user?

[image: Before I enter a number in the form field]

[image: After I entered the number]

[image: If I set the variable as this $kommunenr = '3001'; and remove the echo og the query.]

1. **Before I enter a number in the form field**
2. **After I entered the number**
3. **If I set the variable as this $kommunenr = '3001'; and remove the echo og the query.**

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel really stupid! I should use sessions and globals!

Start each page with session_start(); and first set and then use the global variables:

```
$_SESSION["kommunenr"] = $kommunenr;

$kommunenr = $_SESSION["kommunenr"];
```